# Pagination for EXTJS 4.2 grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have a ext js 4.2 grid with two locked columns.Now i want to add feature of pagination in in my grid.I want it to look like a progress bar pager given on the link
 http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.4/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#progress-bar-pager
Now how can i convert my grid to progress bar pager grid with pagination feature.
My current code is

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title id='title'>HTML Page setup Tutorial</title>       
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-all.css" />       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

Ext.onReady(function() {

   var field=[];   
    var columnList = [];


  var counter = {"levels":

  [
  {"name":"class","samples":[
                          {"name":"1660SH_3","features":[{"count":8,"name":"Bacteroidia"},{"count":9,"name":"Bacteroidiaa"}]},
                          {"name":"1660SH_4","features":[{"count":5,"name":"Bacteroidia"},{"count":6,"name":"Bacteroidiaa"}]}]},
  ]};


      columnList.push({header: "Sample v/s Feature", dataIndex : "Sample v/s Feature",width:0.1*Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,columnLines: true,locked:true});
      field.push("Sample v/s Feature");
        for(var p=0;p<Object.keys(counter.levels[0].samples).length;p++)
        {

        columnList.push({header: counter.levels[0].samples[p].name, dataIndex : counter.levels[0].samples[p].name,flex:1,columnLines: true});
        field.push(counter.levels[0].samples[p].name);
        }
        var Grid7Store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
            fields: field,
            data: [] });





      if(counter.levels[0].name=='class')
      {
        var classTable= Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
          style: 'border: solid Blue 1px',
          id:'family',
          renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
           store :Grid7Store,

          columns : columnList,
          columnLines: true,
          width:Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width,
          height: Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height

      });
         for(var p=0;p<Object.keys(counter.levels[0].samples[0].features).length;p++)
        {
            var s={};
            s["Sample v/s Feature"]='<b>'+counter.levels[0].samples[0].features[p].name+'</b>';
            for(var j=0; j< Object.keys(counter.levels[0].samples).length ;j++)
            {
                s[counter.levels[0].samples[j].name]=counter.levels[0].samples[j].features[p].count;
            }
            Grid7Store.add(s);
        }
      }














});
</script>
  </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to copy the relevant parts from the sample you linked to? Like `xtype: 'pagingtoolbar'` and `pageSize: 10` and everything else that sounds like it could be relevant for paging?

Comment: @Alexander i have edited my code and tried a bit but it did not work....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing the following crucial parts from the original example code:

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager'
]);
```

and

```
plugins: new Ext.ux.ProgressBarPager()
```

and

```
proxy: {
    type: 'memory',
    enablePaging: true,
    data: myData
    reader: {
        type: 'array'
    }
}
```

[I have made a fiddle.](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15ts)

Comment: @Alexander....I have edited my code....I use EXTJS 4.2.....this code of mine works perfectly fine and has pagination feature but now the problem is---->what if i add rows to my store dynamically?...then this wouldn't work?........I get data from server side in JSON format and then i parse that json on extjs ....then using that JSON i add rows to grid store using store.add .................now how would i get data attribute of store and data attribute of proxy...? ...how to do it now....since i don't use mydata variable now and directly add rows from json to store using store.add

Comment: ...i have edited my code....how to implement pagination for such grid in which store data is dynamically added using JSON...counter variable stores the data in JSON format which i get from java(server) side?